# How can I get data off of a Corsair SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

My Corsair SSD won't work and I have some critical data on it that I didn't back up (I needed to create a copy of my mechanical storage device, just forgot). The drive isn't detected by the OS or BIOS. I also tried it on another system, but all that happened was the OS failed to load (my guess was that it knew the drive was there, just couldn't read it). I tried powering it on without the data cable for a bit of time to see if it'd work again, but it didn't. Any ideas of how I can get the data off of this drive without having to send it in?

Comment: what model? I VAGUELY recall some SSDs having major firmware issues

Comment: It's the Corsair Force GT 120.

Comment: I would seriously consider the possibility of firmware related issue like the above commenter suggested. Update your motherboards BIOS, update SATA controller/chipset in windows, and update the firmware for your particular SSD.

Comment: I can't flash the firmware. The drive isn't detected, so I can't use any tools on windows.

Comment: the regular force 120 had issues, and that was what I was thinking of, I suspect.

Comment: I just updated the BIOS and my whole OS broke. I fixed it but gosh, what happened? Didn't know Windows would do such a thing. Anyway, still trying to get it to work. Wish I could try and flash the drive though, but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with linux, I would boot up a linux live cd/dvd, and try to recover data, or see if it is being recognized at all.

For an excellent list of data recovery tools, check out this page on the [forensicswiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery)

As for something a bit more simple, you can try installing [Puran Utilities](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/puran_utilities.html) in Windows. I have had good luck with this tool, but it may not work in this case.

edit: If it is not detected in windows, then the next best option is to use a [linux live cd/dvd](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Category:Live_CD), and/or that list of recovery tools mentioned above.

Comment: It isn't detected on Windows, that's the problem!

Comment: did you try another windows computer? try linux live cd? I have had luck with usb/sata adapters.... attach the usb/sata adpater after a windows boot.

Answer (score 0):

if bios can still see it, get a [linux live cd](http://livecdlist.com/operating-system/linux) (PartedMagic | SystemRescue)and boot into memory and mount the volume and grab your files.